# Overriding bearer token authentication in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an application that uses a mix of MVC pages and SPA pages backed by Web API calls. Web API is configured to use bearer token authentication, and MVC uses cookie authentication. In order to ensure that the cookie and the bearer token are both present & valid, I make a Web API call that requires authorization from an MVC page, and I'm trying to make an equivalent call from a SPA page to a web API method with authentication overridden, something like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)]
    public IHttpActionResult GetIsAuthenticatedCookie()
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }

    //other methods that use bearer token authentication excluded for brevity
}
```

For whatever reason, this does not work; the request is always unauthorized regardless of the presence of a valid cookie. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I could easily replace the call to the method above with a call to an MVC action, which would avoid this problem, but I want to understand why this doesn't work as expected.

I am using MVC v5.2 and Web API v2.2

Comment: 2 questions. What response headers do you get back from the server? What does your web api configuration look like?